# Escaping '&' in File Paths in App.Config CodeBase Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

Suppose you got a folder with an ampersand `&` in its path, and you want to run a .NET app off such folder.

The AppDomain base directory needs no escaping, it can just go as `file:///T:/Te&st/`.
Same for private path of the appdomain. Seemingly, .NET has no problems with bare ampersands in URIs.
But it gets tricky with the `.exe.config` app config file.

It's an XML file, so intuitively I'd just use the regular XML escaping, like this:

```
<cfg:codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="file:///T:/Te&amp;st/Lib/JetBrains.Platform.Util.DLL" />
```

But this fails at runtime. From Fusion `fuslogvw` logs we can learn that it's treating the URI as

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///T:/Test/Lib/JetBrains.Platform.Util.DL.
```

Here, `&` is omitted, and so is the very last character `L`.

Experimentally, I've found that URI-escaping the `U+0026 Ampersand` char saves the day, like this:

```
<cfg:codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="file:///T:/Te%26st/Lib/JetBrains.Platform.Util.DLL" />
```

---

What happens to the XML-escaped ampersand? Which operation could have such an effect, especially dropping the last char?

Which path-legal chars besides `&` might also require escaping?

What would be the most consistent way of constructing a properly-escaped `Uri` object? (`Uri::EscapeUriString` does not consider `&` as requiring any escaping)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you already have a variable with the attribute value.

```
string str = read_attriute_function(); // Your function to load the value as string

Dictionary<string, string> escape_sequences = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// add escape sequences to dictionary
escape_sequences.Add("&amp;", "%26");
escape_sequences.Add("#", "%23");


foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in escape_sequences)
    str = str.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
```

You could alternativly take a look at [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)
Take a look at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc) or at [this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for all escape characters.

---

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: Not quite correct (the attr value would have `"&"` not `"&amp;"` in it, as the conversion is blackboxed by the XML implementation). And does not really answer any of the questions.

Comment: But `#` is a good hint. I've tried some other chars like `'`, and they were OK, but `#` really breaks it down. Though not in app.config but in some other place, like creating an appdomain with base dir, still debugging.

Comment: I'm sorry that I could not be a real help for you :/  I would also like to add that all escape sequences are the hexadecimal value for the characters. You can look them up [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/) and use it like thus: character `'='` has the hex-number `0x3D` --> escape sequence: `%3D`

Comment: I'm using hex numbers for characters in my question already. But actually this raises more questions of what a *hex number* for a character would be, which leads to defining the terms [*charset* and *encoding*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and then differentiating between ASCII and UNICODE percent-escape strategies.

Comment: @hypersw : Yes - you're right. I did not express myself correctly. With 'hex-numbers' I meant the character code.